# Vue login with Azure authentication

Tags: vue.js, azure-active-directory

I am new to Vue and Azure. I have to create a Login frontend using Vue and authenticate by different user roles in Azure.

I wonder how to connect Vue and Azure AD. Please suggest some idea about how we can do that.

Answer (score 0):

`Vue JS` is a JavaScript library. So you can achieve the authentication  with the help of [Microsoft Authentication Library for JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows).

Please refer to the JavaScript code sample which helps you to authenticate [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-auth-code) which uses Auth code flow PKCE as an authentication Mechanism.

Comment: Do i need to use Azure B2C ?

Comment: Hi @deva,  For your current login scenario you do not require B2C.